# htaccess - 404 redirect from different folder into root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I looking for way to redirect any 404 error into index.php

`ErrorDocument 404 /index.php`

Works fine until you have a 404 inside another folder `/about/non-existing-page.php` - in this case it will display `index.php` but the page will be missing styles (as styles are in the root folder).

Any way I can actually user 301 redirect for **ANY (anywhere) 404 error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already said, this is not the redirection page's fault: it's your browser that thinks it's in the `/about` folder. There's nothing you can do in .htaccess to change that: a 301 redirect would change the status code, which is not a good idea.

The easiest solution would be using absolute links in the document:

```
<img src="/images/image.jpg">
```

for completeness' sake, a subsequent 301 can be achieved by using a full URL:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://mydomain/index.php
```

but as said, it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: Not entirely perfect solution. But, it is doing the job. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use absolute links in your 404 document.

If the file is placed in the root, add

```
<base href="/">
```

to the head section of your 404 document and it will be shown correctly even if invoked by a 404 inside a subfolder.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great solution to that 404 directory problem. Also, I didn't know about the base tag. So, I had a bunch of duplicate files that I had for directories at different levels. This helped solve that issue too.